# Time delay indication bar for a text game

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, animation

For a game I am writing in Python 3.6.5, I made a text-based animation to indicate the passage of time (when chopping a tree or mining a rock, etc). I did a lot of trial and error to get the output how I wanted it, however it seems like I went about it in an overly-complicated way. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to write this.

```
import os
import time


def progress_bar(text,secs):
    bar = '['
    c = 0 #used in sum method to determine number of Xs in bar

    for i in range(0,11):
        print(text+'\n')
        bar = bar.replace(' ','') #get rid of previous spaces added to bar
        num_of_X = sum(c == 'X' for c in bar) #get number of Xs (progress)
        for x in range(0,(10 - num_of_X)): #Fill remaining space after Xs
            bar += ' '
        print(bar + ']') 
        bar += 'X'
        time.sleep(secs)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') #clears terminal

    input('Loading complete!')

progress_bar('Enter Your Text Here!',0.15)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can use `bar.count` rather than your `sum`
2. You can use `' ' * n`, rather than your for loop.
3. You don't need `[` in your `bar`.
4. You don't need to add whitespace, `str.format` can do that for you.

   ```
   >>> '[{:<10}]'.format('XX')
   '[XX        ]'
   ```
5. You don't need the `bar` variable.
6. I'd move the `input` out of the function, as it doesn't have much to do with the bar.
7. You could change the size of the bar with another argument.

```
def progress_bar(text, secs, size=10):
    for i in range(size + 1):
        print('{}\n\n[{:<{}}]'.format(text, 'X' * i, size))
        time.sleep(secs)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

---

You can also remove the need for `os` if your terminal support `\r`. This will mean that you can remove `text` from the function too, as IMO it shouldn't really be there either.

```
def progress_bar(secs, size=10):
    for i in range(size + 1):
        print('\r[{:<{}}]'.format('X' * i, size), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(secs)
    print()

print('Your text here!\n')
progress_bar(0.15)
input('>')
```

Alternately you can use `\b`, this is better if you want to allow text like `bar: []`.

```
def progress_bar(secs, size=10):
    for i in range(size + 1):
        print('[{:<{}}]{}'.format('X' * i, size, '\b' * (size + 2)), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(secs)
    print()

print('bar: ', end='', flush=True)
progress_bar(0.15)
input('>')
```

Comment: I need to learn more about string formatting as you've shown me. I will dive into it now, very helpful answer. Thank you!